# CMD - Copy files from multiple folders to one folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy

I need copy lot of *.txt file from multiple folders to one.

I try use for exp.:

```
xcopy D:\Dokumenty\*.txt D:\final /sy
```

But this make 1:1 copy of folder. I need copy only files to a new folder.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use wildcard (`?*`) in `ROBOCOPY`

```
usage: ROBOCOPY source destination [file [file]...] [options]
```

Transposing your example should look like this:

```
ROBOCOPY "D:\Dokumenty\" "D:\final" *.txt /S
```

Comment: I try this, but it copy files and subfolders.

Comment: @Firejs remove `/S` which is what also make xcopy in your example.

Comment: I strongly suggest running `robocopy` with multiple threads: Try to compare using the `/mt` switch.

Answer (score 2):

```
for /r "D:\Dokumenty\" %%# in (*.txt) do copy /y "%%~f#" "D:\final"
```

Comment: `Robocopy` will often be much faster than a regular `copy` - especially if you run it with the `/mt` switch.